# Manhwa where the female lead is reincarnated and stands up for herself and runs her duchy better

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

Trying to find the name of this manhwa that I wanted to pick back up.

Plot: This female protagonist (potentially pink-haired?) had an unfortunate life being married to a duke that 'didn't love' her and she was harassed by her mother-in-law. The story opens up with her and her husband being executed by the king and she reincarnates to back when she just married the duke. Rather than having her life play out the same way she decides to be much more confident and stands up to the duke (not being left alone for a few years as he fights in some war, demonic beasts or rebels or something else like that). She stands up to her evil mother-in-law and puts her in her place. The FL then starts taking her duties as duchess seriously and tries to help the land (like getting connections with her merchant family or planting crops that grow in the infected soil). The other notable part is that she believes that the duke didn't love her and so is confused/embarrassed when she gets obvious affection, shocker.

The last place I left off was she hired a countess to be her lady-in-waiting after that girl was harassed/assaulted by some scumbag noble.

Hopefully, this helps even though this is generic plot #5.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say you haven't read it in "a while;" is that a month, a year, or several years?  Where did you read it, or at least where are the places where you go to read manhwa?

Comment: Probably haven’t read this in 4-6 months. I’m not sure if the specific site I read this on but think of places like topmanwha, zinmanga, and other similar sites. I haven’t seen it posted on more popular sites like asurascans or reaperscans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[Leveling Up My Husband to the Max](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/onufxj7/leveling-up-my-husband-to-the-max)***.

> A cold, uncaring husband, and unreasonable mother-in-law, and a wrongful death — could your life get any worse? What if you were given a chance to change things? When Amber is sent ten years back in time at the moment of her execution, she finds herself face to face with the younger version of her husband, but something’s different about him... He’s completely at her beck and call! Will she be able to prevent the past from repeating itself, or will her life spiral into misery once again? Operation: Leveling Up My Husband to the Max begins now!

A young noblewoman, Lady Amber Riarte (who has red hair), is compelled by royal decree to leave her home and family and move to a cold, harsh territory, where she's to marry and live in the abode of Duke Carlyx Talessdo, a man she's never met.

They remain married for ten years, but spend little time together, as he's away for long periods, dispatching monsters in the region. When he does return home, he's so mentally scarred from his experiences on the battlefield that he can't open up to his wife, emotionally; as a result, she thinks he doesn't love her. She also has to put up with her domineering mother-in-law, who lives with them and treats her very poorly.

Amber's first life comes to an end when she and her husband are accused of treason and taken prisoner by the emperor, who personally executes Amber with a magic sword. She then wakes up ten years prior, on the night of her wedding, and decides to become much more proactive and assertive than she was in her previous life.

She persuades her husband to spend less time away, stands up to her mother-in-law, and takes a more active role in solving problems in the region, such as poor crop yields caused by poisoned soil. She also hires the daughter of a count to be her lady-in-waiting, and humbles an arrogant merchant who'd harassed the niece of a count.

The manhwa is available to read on [Webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/leveling-up-my-husband-to-the-max/list?title_no=3311&page=1).